# NSMutableArray objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have NSMutableArray "Tag" with objects on index 0: "data", "data1", "data2" on index 1: "data3" on index 2: "data2" ...
My chosen_tag is "data2". How to get index 0 and 2. I use Tableview to show my results in cell. NSLog show index 9223372036854775807

```
NSUInteger index = [Tag indexOfObject:chosen_tag];
```

My cell:

```
  UILabel * cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
           [cellLabel setText:[Name objectAtIndex:index]];
```

If I NSLog my NSMutableArray Tag it show `( "data, data1, data2", "data3", "data2, data3, data4, data5, data6", "" )`

Which means data2 is on index 0 and index 2. My problem is that I have "data2" on third place on index 0.

Comment: `9223372036854775807` is `NSNotFound`

Comment: Can you please explain little more about your array? Do you have an array of "data", "data1", "data2" at index 0? Also what's name, it seem like to be another array.

Comment: I have more arrays. I parse from web 4 things and save data in arrays. I need find chosen_tag in array Tag and get index. This index I need to show data in others array.

Comment: My problem is that I have "data2" on third place. If I create new array with "data2" and use [array indexOfObject:chosen_tag] It works.

Comment: Probably not a good time to point out but name of an object should not start with upper case character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get index 0 and 2 ?

You can use the method `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` it returns an `NSIndexSet` object:

```
NSArray *tag = @[@"data, data1, data2", @"data3", @"data2, data3, data4, data5, data6", @""];


NSIndexSet *indexSet = [tag indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    return [[(NSString *)obj componentsSeparatedByString:@", "] containsObject:@"data2"];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", indexSet);
```

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: I wrote: *Assuming all items in Tag ... are arrays*... I updated the answer to consider both arrays and strings.

Comment: NSLog(@"Result: %@",indexSet);  show Result: <_NSCachedIndexSet: 0x7fdf4a6f3210>(no indexes)

Comment: The code works exactly "as is". Probably you have to replace "data2" in the block with your actual string you want to filter. This could happen if you apply the posted pseudo-data to your actual code.

Comment: I replaced with my chosen_tag which is NSString.

Comment: replaced both occurrences?

Comment: Then you provided too little information what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: If I NSLog my NSMutableArray Tag it show (
    "data, data1, data2",
    "data3",
    "data2, data3, data4, data5, data6",
    ""
)

Comment: OK, then all items in the array are lists in form of comma separated strings. I updated the answer again according to the latest information.

Comment: It works but how can I use this in my cellLabel: [Name objectAtIndex:indexSet]

Comment: `indexSet` contains multiple indexes (0 and 2). Which one do you need?

Comment: I need all indexes and show data in others arrays to cellLabel. Like indexPath.row. I tried [Name objectAtIndex:indexSet.firstIndex] and it works.

Answer (score 0):

That index

> 9223372036854775807

May equate to `NSNotFound` meaning that tag is not in the array.

Comment: chosen_tag is in array Tag but on third place of index 0.

Comment: It needs to be an exact match